# Refresh contents of one form from another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to refresh a few  text boxes that are on the main startup form Form 1 when a user clicks a button on Form 2. Basically the textboxes will store the real-time stock.

Here is what I have tried so far :

- Calling `form1.subThatRefreshesTextboxes` from form2.
- placing refresh code in form1.activated code

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO, please take some time to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a clean way to do this,

First, in Form 1, you create a `Public Sub` that will Refresh() your TextBox. Then, from Form 2, you call the Sub of Form1.

```
Public Class Form1

    'Some code here

    Public Sub RefreshMyTextBox()
        If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() RefreshMyTextBox())
        Else
            'Code to refresh your textbox here
        End If
    End Sub

    'Some code there

End Class
```

And on Form 2

```
Public Class Form2

    'Some code here

    private _form1 As Form1 'You need a reference to Form1

    Private Sub Button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        'Whenever you need it, call the Form1.RefreshMyTextBox
        Me._form1.RefreshMyTextBox()
    End Sub

    'Some code there

End Class
```

Comment: There are a few things I noticed. You don't want to check if the form needs invoked, you need to check the textbox. Also in Form2 how do you know you have a reference to Form1 as nothing shows Form1 being passed. Finally why create a private variable of form1 and not use it?... Also the OP hasn't tried anything to show an attempt, you mention this in the comment above so please don't condone this.

Comment: @Zaggler The CheckBox is created by the same Thread than Form1, so it is basically the same. I don't know where the reference comes from because I didn't see any code from OP so if he posts it I might alter my answer. _form1 is used when called to refresh the textbox (edited answer). And last point you're right, I made a mistake I shouldn't have, but shouldn't have been downvoted though...

Comment: @Zaggler Although OP did not provide much attempted stuff, this answer still requires him to do some effort in implementing it.